# How to tell typescript that an inputs event.currentTarget.value us a number?

Tags: typescript

I have a `<input type="number">`. How can I tell TypeScript this? As it is below, TypeScript thinks that event.currentTarget.value is a string.

```
private handleChange = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    this.props.onChange(event.currentTarget.value);
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input type purpose is to serve as a kind of keyboard validation but the value will be a string. [Please see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35791767/html-input-type-number-still-returning-a-string-when-accessed-from-javascript)

So, as @user1283776 said: use `event.currentTarget.valueAsNumber`

Answer (score 1):

Coerce it to a number perhaps?

```
private handleChange = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    this.props.onChange(+event.currentTarget.value);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.currentTarget.valueAsNumber` instead of `event.currentTarget.value`