# Stripe checkout disabled by specific JavaScript statement on page

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I have implemented Stripe's Client-Only Dashboard Checkout (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client) on an html page. I changed the `quantity` value in the Stripe JS code from the integer, 1, to a variable of my choosing called `numb`. I made no other changes to Stripe's JS code.

If I use my own JS code to change the value of `numb` to an integer of my choice then when I click the Checkout button the Stripe Checkout Page has updated the quantity and total price to reflect the value of `numb`. This is what I want.

The problem comes when, instead of `numb = 2;`, I use a JS statement which allows the user of the html page to change the value of `numb`. Here is the section of code:

```
  <P>How many tickets do you want to buy?</p>
  <input type="number" id="steve-number-tickets">
  <button id="steve-testing">How many?</button>

  <p id="test-for-numb"></p>

  <script>
    // ***MY CODE***
    numb = 7;
    // User Chooses
    var howManyButton = document.getElementById('steve-testing');
    howManyButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
      numb = 2;
      // numb = document.getElementById('steve-number-tickets').value;
      // document.getElementById('test-for-numb').innerHTML = numb;
    });
    // ***END OF MY CODE***
  </script>
```

With the code above as it is, I get the following behaviour. If the user refreshes the page and just clicks on the *Checkout* button, Stripe checkout bills them for 7 items. If they refresh the page and click my *How Many?* button and then the *Checkout* button, Stripe checkout bills them for 2 items.

If I change the code so `numb = 2` is commented out and comments are removed from `numb = document.getElementById('steve-number-tickets').value;`, then if the user refreshes the page and clicks on the *Checkout* button, Stripe chekout bills them for 7 items. If they refresh the page and click my *How Many?* button (whether or not they first enter an integer into the *input* element) and then click on the Stripe *Checkout* button, Stripe checkout fails to load.

I thought it must be a problem with the statement: `numb = document.getElementById('steve-number-tickets').value;`. So, I tested that by uncommenting the statement `document.getElementById('test-for-numb').innerHTML = numb;`. When I do that, the value the user entered in the *input* element is displayed in the *p* element with *id="test-for-numb"* when they click on the *How Many?* button. So, that statement does work as expected.

I am unable to understand why Stripe checkout fails to load when I use the statement `numb = document.getElementById('steve-number-tickets').value;` but does load when I use `numb = 2;`.

I would really like to know what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `value` of an input is [always a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35792393/12474862) -- the `type=number` only affects the UI, not the value type. You just need to wrap that in [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to get an actual number, which is what the Checkout API expects.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!