# Adding integers in JavaScript in the form of Variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, integer

```js
function abc() 
{
  var para = document.getElementById("paragraph");
  var inpu = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var inpu_small = inpu - 10;
  var inpu_big = inpu + 10;
   
  para.innerHTML = inpu + " comes between " + inpu_small + " and " + inpu_big + ".";
}
```

```css
#para{
  font-size: 38px;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="number" id="input">
  <button id="submit" onclick="abc()"> Submit</button>
  <p id="paragraph">here</p> 
</body>
</html>
```

**Instead of Summing, It is being added after the input.**
**I want it to ad in the input and show the result, please help me figure out this problem.**

Comment: Add `+` before the value and it would work. `var inpu = +document.getElementById("input").value;`

Answer (score 2):

When you access the input value here:

```
  var inpu = document.getElementById("input").value;
```

In this case, the type of `inpu` is a string. JS behaves weird when you try to do binary operations such as addition and subtraction when one input is a string and the other is an integer (i.e. while subtracting it treats the string as an int but while adding it will treat the int as a string)

You might want to do something like `parseInt(inpu)` to first convert the string to an integer with which you can perform those calculations.

```js
function abc() {
  var para = document.getElementById("paragraph");
  var inpu = parseInt( document.getElementById("input").value );
  //or
  //var inpu = +document.getElementById("input").value;
  var inpu_small = inpu - 10;
  var inpu_big = inpu + 10;

  para.innerHTML = inpu + " comes between " + inpu_small + " and " + inpu_big + ".";
}
```

```css
#para {
  font-size: 38px;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input">
<button id="submit" onclick="abc()"> Submit</button>
<p id="paragraph">here</p>
```

Comment: It would be more clear to OP if you code that returns the output as OP intended. It helps OP to understand in a practical way...

Comment: @decpk Alright 

Answer (score 1):

It will works fine try

```js
function abc() 
{
  var para = document.getElementById("paragraph");
  var inpu = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var inpu_small = inpu - 10;
  var inpu_big = Number(inpu) + 10;
   
  para.innerHTML = inpu + " comes between " + inpu_small + " and " + inpu_big + ".";
}
```

```css
#para{
  font-size: 38px;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input">
  <button id="submit" onclick="abc()"> Submit</button>
  <p id="paragraph">here</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is because the `input` value will always be in the form of a string and you have to **typecast** it in the numeric form.

Now there are two ways you can achieve this:

- parseInt()
- **+** before the value

1. Example with `parseInt`:

```js
function abc() {
  var para = document.getElementById("paragraph");
  var inpu = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var inpu_small = parseInt(inpu) - 10;
  var inpu_big = parseInt(inpu) + 10;

  para.innerHTML = inpu + " comes between " + inpu_small + " and " + inpu_big + ".";
}
```

```css
#para {
  font-size: 38px;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input">
<button id="submit" onclick="abc()"> Submit</button>
<p id="paragraph">here</p>
```

2. Example with **+** symbol:

```js
function abc() {
  var para = document.getElementById("paragraph");
  var inpu = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var inpu_small = +inpu - 10;
  var inpu_big = +inpu + 10;

  para.innerHTML = inpu + " comes between " + inpu_small + " and " + inpu_big + ".";
}
```

```css
#para {
  font-size: 38px;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input">
<button id="submit" onclick="abc()"> Submit</button>
<p id="paragraph">here</p>
```

Comment: but i defined the input as number in html

Comment: @YashDhankhar read out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35791767/html-input-type-number-still-returning-a-string-when-accessed-from-javascript