# Handle onChange on input type=number

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input, setstate

The default state is a number, adding and subtracting from the default state works as expected. When the input value is changed by typing a number in the input field the state changes to a string. What's wrong here?

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState(1);

 const handleChange = e => {
        setValue(e.target.value)
    }
    const handleAdd = () => {
        setValue(value+1)
    }
    const handleSubtract = () => {
        setValue(value-1)
    }
return (
<input type='number' value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
<button label='+' onClick={handleAdd} />
<button label='-' onClick={handleSubtract} />
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35791893/5309084):

> The purpose of the number type is that mobile browsers use this for showing the right keyboards and some browsers use this for validation purposes.

To fix this, there is some approaches. But I suggest to you to `parseInt` the value when `onChange`. So:

```
  const [value, setValue] = useState(1);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue(parseInt(e.target.value));
  };
  const handleAdd = () => {
    setValue((prev) => prev + 1);
  };
  const handleSubtract = () => {
    setValue((prev) => prev - 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="number" value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
      <button label="+" onClick={handleAdd} />
      <button label="-" onClick={handleSubtract} />
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

> What's wrong here?

e.target.value is a string, even if you type a number, you will be given a string in your event

```
setValue(e.target.value)
```

Your state now has a string inside it

```
setValue((prev) => prev - 1);
```

Your add and subtract methods now are working with a string and a number, you are now victim of coercion
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839/

'2' + 1 = 21, so after your state becomes a string, your code won't work as you intended

You need to use parseInt as written in another answer, or parse in any way you want, but always make sure your state has the type you intended

```
const handleChange = e => {
        setValue(Number(e.target.value) || 0)
    }
```

That is another way, note that when parsing a string that cannot become a number you get NaN, the above code will make it become 0 instead, but you can handle it your way