# Even after making the datatype as int why javascript is taking it as string

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom-events

I was doing some of my practical exam codeing.

Below is one of them:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>program 6</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form >
    <label for="first_number">Enter the First Number:</label>
    <input type="number" id="first_number">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="second_number">Enter the Second Number:</label>
    <input type="number" id="second_number">
    <p>Press the button according to your requirement</p>
    <button type="submit" id="add">Sum</button>
    <button type="submit" id="Multiply">Multiply</button>
    <p id="result"></p>
  </form>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
      var a = document.getElementById("first_number").value;
      a = Number(a);
      var b = document.getElementById("second_number").value;
      b = Number(b);
      console.log(typeof a);
      var c = a+b;
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The sum of " + a + " and " + b + " is " + c;
      e.preventDefault();
    })
    document.getElementById("Multiply").addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
      var a = document.getElementById("first_number").value;
      a = Number(a);
      var b = document.getElementById("second_number").value;
      b = Number(b);
      console.log(typeof a);
      var c = a*b;
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The sum of " + a + " and " + b + " is " + c;
      e.preventDefault();
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

DEMO:

```js
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  var a = document.getElementById("first_number").value;
  a = Number(a);
  var b = document.getElementById("second_number").value;
  b = Number(b);
  console.log(typeof a);
  var c = a + b;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The sum of " + a + " and " + b + " is " + c;
  e.preventDefault();
})
document.getElementById("Multiply").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  var a = document.getElementById("first_number").value;
  a = Number(a);
  var b = document.getElementById("second_number").value;
  b = Number(b);
  console.log(typeof a);
  var c = a * b;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The sum of " + a + " and " + b + " is " + c;
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="first_number">Enter the First Number:</label>
  <input type="number" id="first_number">
  <br>
  <br>
  <label for="second_number">Enter the Second Number:</label>
  <input type="number" id="second_number">
  <p>Press the button according to your requirement</p>
  <button type="submit" id="add">Sum</button>
  <button type="submit" id="Multiply">Multiply</button>
  <p id="result"></p>
</form>
```

My question is as you can see I have taken the input type as number

```
<input type="number" id="first_number">
```

then also when I take the input from the user using

```
var a = document.getElementById("first_number").value;
          a = Number(a);
```

why the datatype here is string?

Comment: *"why the datatype here is string"* here where? FYI `InputElement.value` will **always be String**. It's your job as a developer to convert the *input value* to the desired type.

Comment: And as you can see the console outputs `"number"`

Comment: [HTML input type="number" still returning a string when accessed from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35791767/html-input-type-number-still-returning-a-string-when-accessed-from-javascript)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks man for clearing my doubt