# can't get the output from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
var weightkg=document.getElementById('weight').value;

    var heightinm=document.getElementById('height').value;
    
    function bmival (weightkg,heightinm){

        var hout=heightinm*2
        var output=weightkg/hout
        //make a full number
             // var r= Math.trunc(o)
             
         if (output<=18.5){
            return document.getElementById('print').innerHTML=`Your BMI is ${output} you are underweight` ;
         }
 
         else if(output>18.5 && o<25.5){
            return document.getElementById('print').innerHTML=`Your BMI is ${output} You come under fit catogery`;
         }
 
         else{
            return document.getElementById('print').innerHTML=`Your BMI is ${output} you are overweight and obese`;
         }
     }
```

**[i am making a bmi cal that take input from user but i am getting a error and don't know what i am doing wrong]**

**
[this is js code and when i run i get a NaN instead of Number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8g8Sr.png)  **

Comment: How are you calling this code? You need to get the values of the inputs when they click the button to calculate, not when the page starts.

Comment: The global variable names `weightkg` and `heightinm` are the same as your function argument names, which is really confusing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML input type="number" still returning a string when accessed from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35791767/html-input-type-number-still-returning-a-string-when-accessed-from-javascript)

Comment: You will need to show the relevant part of your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you get from

```
var weightkg=document.getElementById('weight').value;
```

seems to be a string instead of number. You need to convert values to do Math operations on them. NaN tells you `output` is not a number. Turn your values to number with parseInt method.

```
var weightkg = parseInt(document.getElementById('weight').value);
```

or you can just put a "+" to convert a string into number

```
var weightkg = +document.getElementById('weight').value;
```

For Example.

```
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const defaultStringInput = document.getElementById('input').value;
const inputConverted = parseInt(document.getElementById('input').value);
const inputConverted2 = +document.getElementById('input').value;
input.addEventListener('change', () => {

  console.log(typeof defaultStringInput); // string
  console.log(typeof inputConverted); // number
  console.log(typeof inputConverted2); // number
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The values from an input field are strings so you must convert them into numbers

```js
var heightinm = +document.getElementById('height').value; // one way to do it.
```